# SharePoint Add-in & Wildcard Certificates

Tags: sharepoint-addin

According to Microsoft documentation:
"You need a wildcard certificate instead of individual certificates because each installed app has its own subdomain."

Is there any other alternative to using a wildcard certificate for SharePoint Add-ins?

My organization will not allow wildcard certificates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of an App-URL looks like this: 
`<Prefix>-<AppID>.<appdomain>.<tld>`

Example: app-1234567890abcdef.sharepointapps.local

Every App you install gets a different AppID in the URL. The App itself gets called via this URL and it is a security best-practice to encrypt this traffic via SSL. As you will get as many different URLs as you install Apps, [Microsoft's guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx) tells you to configure a wildcard-certificate and a wildcard-record in DNS for your AppDomain.

There is a solution which is not very practicable in real-life: You could get the URL of each installed App manually. After that you add a IIS-binding for that URL and assign a new certificate with the specific App-URL. You would also need an additional IP-Address for that binding and you have to create the according record in DNS manually.